# Flink kafka - Message Prioritization

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink pipeline which reads from a kafka topic does a map operation(builds an ElasticSearch model) and sinks it to Elasticsearch

**Pipeline-1:**

> Flink-Kafka-Connector-Consumer(topic1) (parallelism 8) -> Map
> (parallelism 8) -> Flink-Es-connector-Sink(es1) (parallelism 8)

Now i want some messages to be prioritized(processed quickly not necessarily in any order). I am okay in creating a new topic and placing the priority messages in it (or) do a partition based buckets(Ex: https://github.com/riferrei/bucket-priority-pattern i don't think it's possible in flink kafka connector since partition assignment is present inside FlinkKafkaConsumerBase ).

**I tried the below solution:**

I created another topic (topic2 in which i placed the priority messages) and with it a new Flink pipeline

**Pipeline-2:**

> Flink-Kafka-Connector-Consumer(topic2) (parallelism 8) -> Map
> (parallelism 8) -> Flink-Es-connector-Sink(es1) (parallelism 8)

But the problem is, I want to consume topic2 as soon as possible. I can have a delay/slowness in topic1 because of that. If there is no message in topic2 then topic1 should be given more priority. But in the above case both the pipelines are getting processed equally. Increasing the parallelism of pipeline-2 to a big number doesn't help as when there is no message in topic2 then topic1 is still very slow.

How can i achieve this using Flink Kafka connector? Is it possible to achieve it in any other way?

Comment: Could you please clarify the issue in case of scenario with 2 dedicated pipelines ? Priority kafka topic is empty, but first pipeline is slow ? Doesn't this already is what you need - the high pririty messages got processed quickly ?

Comment: @Mikalai Lushchytski If there is no message in priority topic then first pipeline is slow as parallelism is low for the first pipeline. The parallelism assigned to the second pipeline (which is big) is getting wasted at that time.

Comment: I might be wrong, but in https://github.com/riferrei/bucket-priority-pattern#using-the-assignor I can see, that the `BucketPriorityAssignor` is configured via configuration properties which you can pass to `FlinkKafkaConsumer`. So it seems to be possible to configure the same in Flink application.